# Entrar en enlace y abrir dropdown

Tags: javascript, html5

estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:
En una página tengo varios enlaces

```html
<section class="ac-container">
<div>
 <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
 <label for="ac-1">About us</label>
 <article class="ac-small">
  <p>Some content... </p>
 </article>
</div>
<div>
 <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" checked />
 <label for="ac-2">How we work</label>
 <article class="ac-medium">
  <p>Some content... </p>
 </article>
</div>
<div><!--...--></div>
</section>
```

Estos enlaces llevan a una página donde hay un dropdown con un titular y una descripcion (adjunto imagen)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer que dependiendo en qué enlace haga clic me lleve a página de desplegables y me abra uno en concreto?

A ver si me podeis ayudar, porque no se bien como puedo hacerlo..

```css
.ac-container{
 width: 400px;
 margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
}

.ac-container label{
 font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 20;
 display: block;
 height: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #777;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
 line-height: 33px;
 font-size: 19px;
 background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
 box-shadow: 
  0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
  1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9) inset, 
  0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.ac-container label:hover{
 background: #fff;
}

.ac-container input:checked + label,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover{
 background: #c6e1ec;
 color: #3d7489;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
 box-shadow: 
  0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
  0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.ac-container label:hover:after,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 right: 13px;
 top: 7px;
 background: transparent url(../images/arrow_down.png) no-repeat center center; 
}

.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
 background-image: url(../images/arrow_up.png);
}

.ac-container input{
 display: none;
}

.ac-container article{
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 margin-top: -1px;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 0px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 transition: 
  height 0.3s ease-in-out, 
  box-shadow 0.6s linear;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article{
 transition: 
  height 0.5s ease-in-out, 
  box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3);
}

.ac-container article p{
 font-style: italic;
 color: #777;
 line-height: 23px;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 20px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small{
 height: 140px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-medium{
 height: 180px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-large{
 height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<section class="ac-container">
 <div>
  <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="ac-1">About us</label>
  <article class="ac-small">
   <p>Some content... </p>
  </article>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" checked />
  <label for="ac-2">How we work</label>
  <article class="ac-medium">
   <p>Some content... </p>
  </article>
 </div>
 <div><!--...--></div>
</section>


//asi quedaria
    <?php
 if(isset($_GET['servicio'])) $servicio = $_GET['servicio']; else $servicio = "";
 ?>
   
    
<div id="accordion">
 <h4 class="accordion-toggle"><span><?php if($servicio == "consultoria") echo "-"; else echo "+";?></span><?php echo $titulo1; ?></h4>
 <div class="accordion-content<?php if($servicio == "consultoria") echo " default";?>">
```

Este es el código que he podido conseguir,
lo he encontrado en http://www.ajaxshake.com/plugin/ES/1056/53d8efde/menu-acordeon-con-css3-css3acordion.html
y es básicamente la idea de lo que quiero hacer, **solo que cuando acceso a esta página a través de un enlace quiero que se abra un acordeón dependiendo del lugar de donde venga.**

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cual es tu propósito, quiero decir, cuando tu cliques en uno de los enlaces, que te lleve siempre a la misma página, pero dependiendo del enlace, te lleve abra un desplegable u otro por defecto?

Comment: html no maneja variables por lo tanto lo que intentas hacer es raro si fuera php fuera facil `<a href="servicio2.php?id=1">Servicio 2</a> //y lo obtienes con $_GET y una condicion`

Comment: falta información, no indicas servicioN.html  es un documento estatico, o generado por el backend, si usas un framework como angular, si solo lo quieres conseguir con javascript nativo ...  Aunque tenggo varias soluciones no se muy bien con que responderte :/. Es servicionN.html el mismo siempre ?

Comment: Puedo usar php, el archivo es .php así que sería valida una opción en php  si podrías ayudarme :)

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacerlo con anclas, añadiendo a la url el id de la sección a la que quieres llegar, mas o menos asi:

`<a href="servicios.html/#servicio3">Servicio 3</a>`

Para que te despliegue la sección deberias hacerlo con javascript, o bien puedes probar con css, con el [selector :target](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) mas o menos asi, para que te encienda el div siguiente al anchor (que deberia estar oculto previamente con ´display:none´ o como sea):

```
.div:target + div{
 display:block;
}
```

EDITO:
Te pongo una solucion JS, prueba a añadir en la pagina de destino este js, que te añadirá al id del url la clase "open" (o la que sea necesaria para abrirlo):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var destino=window.location.hash.substr(1);
$("#"+destino).addClass("open");
});
```

Comment: Puedo hacer con javascript que al enlace que se haga clic le aplique la case .div:target + div para que lo abra ,o hay otra forma?

Comment: No, a ver,  :target es un selector que se aplica al elemento que tenga el ancla despues de pulsarla. Es decir, si pulsas el enlace a `servicios.html/#servicio3`ese id entra en estado :target y se le aplican las propiedades que le digas en el css.
De todas formas, funcionara mejor y mas limpiamente si le aplicas una clase con JS.
Al arrancar haces ´$(location).attr('hash');´y con eso tienes el id y le puedes aplicar una clase

Comment: En tu respuesta estas presuponiendo cosas que no quedan claras, como que los elementos a mostrar u ocutar, tienen una opacidad a 0, cuando lo que posiblemente estará quitando, es el display. 
Y con el css que pones.. estas dando opacidad: 1 a los div que haya dentro del div targeteado.
La idea no es del todo mala, pero falta información, y ampliar la respuesta para ser más preciso.

Comment: He editado la pregunta y he añadido el acordeón que he usado, necesito que dependiendo del enlace que me lleve a la página del acordeón se abra un elemento del acordeón u otro, no sé como hacer que el acordeón reaccione a este evento :S ¿Podría ser utilizando el atributo checked de alguna forma?

Comment: @Jorgesys entiendo lo de poder añadirle una clase, pero no sé como hacer para que dependiendo de qué enlace seleccionse se abra un drop u otro... ¿Podrís aportarme algo más de información para poder solucionar esta encrucijada?

Comment: @Montaycabe con el selector # no se abre automatico cuando hago click, necesito intentar otra posible solución.

Comment: @AntonioÁngelEstradaPérez He editado la respuesta para ponerte mas o menos como se podria hacer con jquery

Comment: Gracias @Montaycabe , al final he conseguido llevarlo a cabo con el uso de get en la petición.